# Proof of conditional expectation example

Tags: conditional-expectation

Can someone tell me if I made any mistakes on this proof :

prove :$$E(X|A)=\frac{E[XI_a]}{P(A)}$$
where $I_a=1$ if event A occurs, else $I_a=0$.

$$E(XI_a)=I_aE(E(X|A))=I_a\sum_AE(X|A)p(A)=E(X|A)p(A)$$
With the last equality being true because $A\neq0=>I_a=0$
$$E(X|A)p(A)=E(XI_a)=>E(XI_a)/p(A)=E(X|A)
$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb E[X\mid A]$ ? To me $\frac{1}{\mathbb P(A)}\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_A]$ is the definition.

Comment: The expectation of X given some event A occurs

Comment: I know what it mean ! But how do you defined it ? To me, the definition of $\mathbb E[X\mid A]$ is precisely $\frac{1}{\mathbb P(A)}\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_A]$. By the way, Wikipedia has the same definition as me as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)

Comment: You can verify first for an indicator function, then to step function, and using the machinery to positive random variable and all random variables etc.